# How to compare the sum of the square of the elements of two arrays?

Tags: python

I'm doing katas (practices) at [codewars.com](https://www.codewars.com/kata/56ff6a70e1a63ccdfa0001b1/train/python) to practice the learning I'm getting in Python. This is the kata :

> Given two integer arrays `a`, `b`, both of length `>= 1`, create a program
>   that returns `True` if the sum of the squares of each element in `a` is
>   strictly greater than the sum of the square of each element in `b`.

This is the code that I tried:

```
def array_madness(a,b):
    a = sum(i**2 for i in a)
    b = sum(i**2 for i in b)

    return True if a > b else False
```

This is the test I need to pass:

```
test.assert_equals(array_madness([4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]),True)
test.assert_equals(array_madness( [1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]),False)
```

Comment: you mentioned cubes, shouldnt b be **3?

Comment: @Luv I´m sorry, I fix it. It´s square.

Comment: i'm not sure what's the question/error?

Comment: @lhd I have published the url of the challenge that I am trying to overcome. I also placed the tests that I have to pass. When you put the code that I have achieved so far, it returns an error that says: True should equal False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You copied the problem description wrong.  It's the sum of the *squares* of `a`, and the sum of the *cubes* of `b` (it's doing a different calculation for the two arrays).  The following should work:

```
def array_madness(a,b):
    return sum(i**2 for i in a) > sum(i**3 for i in b)
```

Comment: Thank you to much. I understand now.